# Excel: Compare delimited values in 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wonder if anyone can help with this, I've had a couple goes and got close, but no cigar.

I have delimited values (text) in C2 separated by a pipe (|). I have delimited values in D2 also separated by a |. In some cases values in C2 or D2 can contain a single value with no separator.

I'd like to have a formula in E2 that shows True or False if any value in D2 is present among any values in C2.

This is as close as I got, but still some errors. Errors where the 2 cells contain the same values but in a different order, sometimes errors when there are multiple values identical in both cells. But many correct answers. Which is making it almost impossible to trouble shoot as I don't see the connection between the errors.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|",D2)), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|",C2)), SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"|",REPT(" ",LEN(C2))), (ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"|",""))+1))-1)*LEN(C2)+1, LEN(C2))), TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"|",REPT(" ",LEN(D2))), (ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"|",""))+1))-1)*LEN(D2)+1, LEN(D2))))))>0, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2, D2)), "True", "False")), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2, C2)), "True", "False"))
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(D2,"|"),TEXTSPLICT(C2,"|"),0)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I think as I've learned more over the years, I make the same number of errors as I did when I started, I just seem to write longer, more complex errors. This is beautifully simple, works well and reminds me that I am still a beginner, even if I get some things right some of the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=OR(XLOOKUP("*|"&TEXTSPLIT(C2,"|")&"|*","|"&D2&"|",1,0,2))
```